# A proof involving fundamental system (ODEs)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations

Lets suppose that we know the fundamental system (and it exists) ; we want to find a solution $L[x]=f(t)$.

Let $\forall s \; x(t,s)$ be the solution of a system:

$\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
L[x]=0 \\
x(t_0)=0, x'(t_0)=0, ... , x^{(n-2)}(t_0)=0,x^{(n-1)}(t_0)=1
\end{array} \right.$

then $y(t)=\int_{t_0}^{t} x(t,s)f(s)ds$ is a solution of:

$\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
L[x]=f(t) \\
x^{k}(t_0)=0, k=0,1,...,n-2
\end{array} \right.$

So I have to prove that fact, but don't really know how to proceed. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you have $x(t_0)=\ldots=x^{(n-2)}(t_0)=0$, $x^{(n-1)}(t_0)=1$, and **not** $x(s)=\ldots=x^{(n-2)}(s)=0$, $x^{(n-1)}(s)=1$? It seems that the former doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I just double checked it, and it's ok. Although I'm not 100% sure, because it's written in my notebook, it's a fact from the lecture that I'm supposed to prove, but don't know how.

Comment: I do not mean what you are supposed to prove (that's O.K), but what is in line 5 from above (the second line of the first display): in $x(t,s)$, what is the role of $s$?